# Laravel 8 and Digitalocean spaces storage upload

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-s3, laravel-8, digital-ocean

Anyone did success for upload to Digitalocean spaces for laravel 8

here is my composer

```
"laravel/framework": "^8.54",
"league/flysystem-aws-s3-v3": "^1.0",
```

in filesystems.php

```
'spaces' => [
   'driver' => 's3',
   'key' => env('SPACES_ACCESS_KEY_ID', '===AAACESS KEY==='),
   'secret' => env('SPACES_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY', '===BBBSECRECT KEY==='),
   'region' => env('SPACES_DEFAULT_REGION', 'sgp1'),
   'bucket' => env('SPACES_BUCKET', 'laravel-spaces'),
   'url' => env('SPACES_URL', 'https://laravel-spaces.sgp1.cdn.digitaloceanspaces.com'),
   'endpoint' => env('SPACES_ENDPOINT', 'https://sgp1.digitaloceanspaces.com')
],
```

Tinker upload test

```
$path = 'thumb.png';
$file = Storage::disk('spaces')->put($path, @file_get_contents(public_path('images/logo.png')));
```

Errors

```
Aws\S3\Exception\S3Exception with message 'Error executing "PutObject" on "https://laravel-spaces.s3.sgp1.amazonaws.com/thumb.png"; AWS HTTP error: cURL error 6: Could not resolve: laravel-spaces.s3.sgp1.amazonaws.com (Domain name not found) (see https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html) for https://laravel-spaces.s3.sgp1.amazonaws.com/thumb.png'
*** Execution finished ***
```

Why append s3 and amazonaws.com to url

And how to solve this

Thanks.

Comment: Check `config('filesystems.disks.spaces')` in `php artisan tinker`. Make sure it's showing the right config; perhaps you've got a cached one? I don't see anything obviously wrong otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks all for help.
I am solved problem, problem by .env file config wrong.

this is right config

```
SPACES_ACCESS_KEY_ID=AAAAA
SPACES_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=BBBB
SPACES_DEFAULT_REGION=sgp1
SPACES_BUCKET=mybucket
SPACES_ENDPOINT=https://mybucket.sgp1.digitaloceanspaces.com
SPACES_URL=https://mybucket.sgp1.cdn.digitaloceanspaces.com
```

And Config

```
'spaces' => [
  'driver' => 's3',
  'key' => env('SPACES_ACCESS_KEY_ID'),
  'secret' => env('SPACES_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'),
  'region' => env('SPACES_DEFAULT_REGION'),
  'bucket' => env('SPACES_BUCKET'),
  'url' => env('SPACES_URL'),
  'endpoint' => env('SPACES_ENDPOINT'),
  'bucket_endpoint' => true,
  'visibility' => 'public',
],
```

Answer (score 0):

Your error is telling you exactly what the issue is

```
Aws\S3\Exception\S3Exception with message 'Error executing "PutObject" on "https://laravel-spaces.s3.sgp1.amazonaws.com/thumb.png"; AWS HTTP error: cURL error 6: Could not resolve: laravel-spaces.s3.sgp1.amazonaws.com (Domain name not found) (see https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html) for https://laravel-spaces.s3.sgp1.amazonaws.com/thumb.png'
*** Execution finished ***
```

It cannot resolve sgp1.amazonaws.com - this means there is something missing inside your ENV file. Without seeing the env file I could not tell you.

That being said, I get what you are trying to do inside filesystems.php - but you should set all variables inside ENV regardless of what you set the fallback to

Comment: You're missing the point of OP's question; they're using DigitalOcean's S3-compatiable endpoints. It should be putting to `sgp1.digitaloceanspaces.com` based on OP's config, not `s3.sgp1.amazonaws.com` at all.

Comment: @ceejayoz I am NOT missing their point. They have filesystems.php setup but the error is still AWS. There is more code needed to troubleshoot and/or we need to see the .env file

Comment: It shouldn't be hitting amazonaws.com at all; that's what the `endpoint` configuration item is for. It allows pointing the request at an alternative, non-AWS, S3-compatible alternative endpoint like DO. See https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/filesystem#amazon-s3-compatible-filesystems. As far as I can tell, OP's done all the right stuff here; that's why I'm wondering if it's a cached config issue.

Comment: Oh thats possible for sure. ```php artisan config:cache``` would be something I would run as well. Fall short of that - we need to see your ENV file. Also, it would help to see the code you are using.